# strtol using errno

Tags: c, c89

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void main(void)
{
     int data;
     char * tmp;
     data = strtol("23ef23",&tmp,10);
     printf("%d",errno);
     getchar();
}
```

output is 0 ...

why?

i am using visual studio 2010 C++
code must be C89 compatible.

Comment: Well, you *are* purposedly putting `errno=0`.

Comment: sorry it was before the line,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`strtol` only sets `errno` for overflow conditions, not to indicate parsing failures. For that purpose, you have to check the value of the end pointer, but you need to store a pointer to the original string:

```
char const * const str = "blah";
char const * endptr;

int n = strtol(str, &endptr, 0);

if (endptr == str) { /* no conversion was performed */ }

else if (*endptr == '\0') { /* the entire string was converted */ }

else { /* the unconverted rest of the string starts at endptr */ }
```

I think the only required error values are for underflow and overflow.

Conversely, if the entire string has been consumed in the conversion, you have `*endptr = '\0'`, which may be an additional thing you might want to check.

Comment: @slashmais: Just as expected (no conversion is performed).

Comment: @Nahum Litvin: this answer perfectly answers your question, but take note of this site:http://www.cplusplus.com/ it will save you lots of trouble :) (it covers C as well)

Comment: Concerning `errno`.  C11 spec says §7.22.1.4 8 "... If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, ... the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`" appears to go against "no requirement that `strtol` set `errno`".

Comment: Love that "I was young" - just a mere 2 years ago.  IMO 0-30 young, 30-60 middle age, 60-90 old, 90+ wow!

Answer (score 3):

Your logic does not fit with the 'spec'.
see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)
An invalid value does not necessarily set 'errno'.

(copy follows)
long int strtol ( const char * str, char ** endptr, int base );

Convert string to long integer
Parses the C string str interpreting its content as an integral number of the specified base, which is returned as a long int value.

The function first discards as many whitespace characters as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is found. Then, starting from this character, takes as many characters as possible that are valid following a syntax that depends on the base parameter, and interprets them as a numerical value. Finally, a pointer to the first character following the integer representation in str is stored in the object pointed by endptr.

If the value of base is zero, the syntax expected is similar to that of integer constants, which is formed by a succession of:

An optional plus or minus sign
An optional prefix indicating octal or hexadecimal base ("0" or "0x" respectively)
A sequence of decimal digits (if no base prefix was specified) or either octal or
hexadecimal digits if a specific prefix is present

If the base value is between 2 and 36, the format expected for the integral number is a succession of the valid digits and/or letters needed to represent integers of the specified radix (starting from '0' and up to 'z'/'Z' for radix 36). The sequence may optionally be preceded by a plus or minus sign and, if base is 16, an optional "0x" or "0X" prefix.

If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a valid integral number as defined above, or if no such sequence exists because either str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion is performed.

Parameters
str
    C string containing the representation of an integral number.
endptr
    Reference to an object of type char*, whose value is set by the function to the next character in str after the numerical value.
    This parameter can also be a null pointer, in which case it is not used.

Return Value
On success, the function returns the converted integral number as a long int value.
If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned.
If the correct value is out of the range of representable values, LONG_MAX or 
LONG_MIN is returned, and the global variable errno is set to ERANGE.

Answer (score 3):

It has been 10 years since the question was first posted, but the problem does not age. The answers given are either out of date (yet true for their time) or a bit confusing because I had to search more.

I have seen this in a book and met this post while searching for its meaning, and while checking the page for `strtol`, I ended up in [this page on cplusplus.com of `errno` macro](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/).

Your question has 2 parts to answer here:

First lets make a note of these 2 things about `errno`:

1- `errno` can be anything during the execution of a program for no function resets it (unless your own function does so)

> errno is set to zero at program startup ...
> any function ... can modify its value ...
> no ... function sets its value back to zero

2- one has to reset it before calling a function that may use it.

> should be reset ... to zero before the call ... since ... previous  ... function may have altered its value

your program is pretty small, so no function seems to be there to change it. The sole visitors of `errno` are `main` program to set it to zero, and `strtol` in case of any error.

Yet, your program shows `errno is 0`, and this is confusing because one expects `23ef23` would not be converted to a number since it includes letters in it. However, this expectation is wrong, and actually, you get a number from this string thus there is really no error here, so no change is made to `errno`. and this makes the second part of the answer.

you will find this definition in [strtol page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

> ... takes as many characters as possible that are valid following a
> syntax that depends on the base parameter, and interprets them as a
> numerical value ... a pointer to the first character following is
> stored.

instead of a long explanation, this following print statement and its output will suffice to visualize that above definition:

```
printf("%d %d %s",data,errno,tmp);
23 0 ef23
```

if you set the base to 16, output would be `2354979 0`  . And base 2 would give `0 0 23ef23`, showing that `strtol` will not freak if it does not find a number. The only error it will give will be `ERANGE` for breaching limits:

> If the value read is out of the range of representable values by a
> long int, the function returns LONG_MAX or LONG_MIN (defined in
> ), and errno is set to ERANGE.

Comment: this was a good question, yet only 1 upvote :( last time I wrote in C was 8 years ago, and still very interesting. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `errno` to 0 before you call `strtol`. Otherwise you overwrite whatever value `strtol` set `errno` to.

Comment: What you just said doesn't make any sense.

Setting `errno` to 0 wouldn't prevent it from future overwriting. `strtol` sets errno (if at all), but why would you want to prevent that from being overwritten? Others need to use `errno` too...

However, you might want to store `errno` right after `strtol` to prevent others overwriting it, e.g.: `int myErrno = errno;`

Comment: After a day I gave a second (well, rather 20th) reading of your post. So the first part is correct, but the second part is still nonsense. One would want to `errno = 0;` before calling `strtol`, because otherwise reading `errno` after `strtol` might return the error set but someone else, as `strtol` does not set `errno` to 0 (that is, no error), if it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check `tmp` is not the same as `"blablabla"` pointer.

If `data == 0` and `tmp == "blablabla"`, then the input data is in the incorrect format. `errno` needs not to be set by the implementation if the input data is not in the expected format.

On `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` functions C says:

> (C99, 7.20.1.4p7) If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.
>
> (C99, 7.20.1.4p9) The strtol, strtoll, strtoul, and strtoull functions return the converted
>   value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned.