# checking for strtol unsuccessful conversions

Tags: c, parsing

Basically using strtol to check for unsuccessful conversions,
I am using the function

```
width = (int)  strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
if (errno != 0) {
    printf("Please parse integer argument");
}
```

using `errno.h`

It works when the arguments are characters, i.e.: argv[2] = e, 6, etic
But this fails to catch errors when arguments like 444r or 33f (leading numbers followed by characters) are supplied? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Read the documentation! (Hint: What is that second argument, where you passed `NULL`, for?)

Comment: Additionally, if you cast to `int` before checking, you cannot catch errors like (e.g. for a platform with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long`) an input of 4294967296.

Comment: Also, you should clear errno before calling strtol(). _The strtol() function shall not change the setting of errno if successful._

Comment: This has good information as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792676/103167

Comment: @Dipstick: Where is this quote from? `strtol` may change `errno` on success.

Comment: @mafso: It is part of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001. However the point is that you cannot assume that the value is zero if the conversion succeeded; only that it is non-zero if the conversion failed.

Comment: @Dipstick: Interesting. This seems to be a difference between standard C and POSIX: The former only says that `errno` is set to `ERANGE` if the correct result would over-/underflow, the latter that `errno` is unchanged on success.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the second argument to `strtol()` to receive a pointer to the first character after the number, and check that the character is NUL (i.e. `'\0'`).

Comment: … and check if `*argv[2]` is 0! Or if `errno` could be non-0 although no error occurred.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445171/strtol-using-errno

Answer (score 1):

You should use the second parameter of the function to determine where the parsing was stopped. According to the C Standard

> 7 If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form,
>   no conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the object
>   pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.

As for errno then

> If the correct value is outside the range of representable values,
>   LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or ULLONG_MAX is
>   returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any),
>   and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in **errno**.

It is important to note that if no conversion was done then endptr wilol contain the value of nptr.

Comment: So, `errno` wouldn't be useful to determine input error.